# Windows Mixed Reality is not supported on operating systems prior to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (Redstone 3)

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm trying to launch my first application for Hololens using Unity and I'm getting error when clicking *Play* in Unity

> Windows Mixed Reality is not supported on operating systems prior to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (Redstone 3)

I'm using Windows 8.1 (don't know if it matters, theoretically **Windows 10 Fall Creators Update** is supported on Win 8.1)

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Windows 10 != Windows 8.1. You will have to upgrade Windows.

Comment: "theoretically Windows 10 Fall Creators Update is supported on Win 8.1" well, practically it is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest Windows 10 version as the error says.

Comment: Thanks, after installing Win10 everything is working